# submitting form values to jquery in multiple rows

Tags: jquery, forms

I am having a table of students in which I am making a form in each row to save marks of each student through jquery. [image]

Can anybody guide how is it possible?
I am unable to pick unique values of students.
Here is my code

```
<?php 
              
              if($row!=''){
                foreach($row as $value){
                ?>
                <tr>
                <form>
                <td><?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['student_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['father_name'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <select id="disc_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="form-control opt required " name="disc" >
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Grade</option>
                            <option value="1" >A+</option>
                            <option value="2" >A</option>
                            <option value="3" >B+</option>
                            <option value="4" >B</option>
                            <option value="5" >C</option>
                            <option value="6" >D</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <select id="class_part_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="form-control opt" name="class_part" >
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Grade</option>
                            <option value="1">A+</option>
                            <option value="2">A</option>
                            <option value="3">B+</option>
                            <option value="4">B</option>
                            <option value="5">C</option>
                            <option value="6">D</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <input class="std_marks_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" type="text" name="marks" class="form-control col-sm-8" placeholder="student marks" />
                
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                    
                        <input type="hidden" name="student_name" value="<?php echo $value['student_name'] ?>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $value['student_id'] ?>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="class_id" value="<?php echo $value['class_id'] ?>"/>
                        <input id="save_btn_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Save Marks" />
                    </form>  
                
                </td>
                
              </tr>
                  <?php 
                }
              }
                ?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('select#exam_term').change(function(){
            
            var exam_term = $('#exam_term option:selected').val();
    
            $('#students_table').show(1000);
                $('#save_btn').click(function(){
                
                    var disc = $('#disc option:selected').val(); //$("#dropdownList option:selected").text();
                    var class_part = $('#class_part option:selected').val();
                    var std_marks = $('#std_marks').val();
                    var teacher_id = <?php echo $this->session->id?>;
                    var student_id = <?php echo $student_id?>;
                    var class_id   = <?php echo $class_id?>;
                    var subject_id = <?php echo $subject_id?>;
                    var form_data = {
                        
                                        disc : disc, //$("#dropdownList option:selected").text();
                                        class_part : class_part,
                                        exam_term  : exam_term,
                                        std_marks  : std_marks,
                                        teacher_id : teacher_id,
                                        student_id : student_id,
                                        class_id   : class_id,
                                        subject_id : subject_id
                            
                            };
                        $.ajax({
                                 type:'post',
                                 url:'<?= base_url()?>index.php/teacher/set_formative_marks',
                                // method: 'post',
                                 data : form_data,
                                 success: function(data){
                                            //$(".message").html(data).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                                            //$(".message").fadeOut(1000);
                                            alert (data);
                                            }
                                
                                     
                                });
                });
        });
```

I want to save the values of each student in jquery call to a function in controller.
Had to make unique ids of each student's grno by adding '*' after students_id*. Is there any simpler way to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your button gets clicked you can get closest `tr` from that button using `closest` method and then using this you can use `.find` to get all values which you needed.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('select#exam_term').change(function() {

  var exam_term = $('#exam_term option:selected').val();

  $('#students_table').show(1000);
})

$('.save').click(function() {
  //get closest tr
  var slector = $(this).closest("tr");
  //find values using name attribute
  var disc = slector.find("select[name='disc']").val()
  console.log(disc)
  var class_part = slector.find("select[name='class_part']").val()
  var std_marks = slector.find('input[name=marks]').val();
  var teacher_id = "<?php echo $this->session->id?>";
  var student_id = slector.find('input[name=student_id]').val();
  var class_id = slector.find('input[name=class_id]').val();
  // var subject_id =  slector.find('input[name=subject_id]').val();
  var exam_term = "somedemodata";
  var form_data = {
    disc: disc,
    class_part: class_part,
    exam_term: exam_term,
    std_marks: std_marks,
    teacher_id: teacher_id,
    student_id: student_id,
    class_id: class_id,
    // subject_id: subject_id

  };

  console.log(form_data)
  //yourajax call

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
      12
    </td>
    <td>
      something
    </td>
    <td>
      abc
    </td>
    <td>

      <div class="form-label-group">
        <select id="disc_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="form-control opt required " name="disc">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Grade</option>
          <option value="1">A+</option>
          <option value="2">A</option>
          <option value="3">B+</option>
          <option value="4">B</option>
          <option value="5">C</option>
          <option value="6">D</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-label-group">
        <select id="class_part_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="form-control opt" name="class_part">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Grade</option>
          <option value="1">A+</option>
          <option value="2">A</option>
          <option value="3">B+</option>
          <option value="4">B</option>
          <option value="5">C</option>
          <option value="6">D</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-label-group">
        <input class="std_marks_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" type="text" name="marks" class="form-control col-sm-8" placeholder="student marks" />

      </div>
    </td>
    <td>


      <input type="hidden" name="student_name" value="something" />
      <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="12" />
      <input type="hidden" name="class_id" value="15" />
      <!--added class save and remove input type submit-->
      <input id="save_btn_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm save" type="button" value="Save Marks" />


    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>
      13
    </td>
    <td>
      something1
    </td>
    <td>
      abcd
    </td>
    <td>

      <div class="form-label-group">
        <select id="disc_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="form-control opt required " name="disc">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Grade</option>
          <option value="1">A+</option>
          <option value="2">A</option>
          <option value="3">B+</option>
          <option value="4">B</option>
          <option value="5">C</option>
          <option value="6">D</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-label-group">
        <select id="class_part_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="form-control opt" name="class_part">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Grade</option>
          <option value="1">A+</option>
          <option value="2">A</option>
          <option value="3">B+</option>
          <option value="4">B</option>
          <option value="5">C</option>
          <option value="6">D</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-label-group">
        <input class="std_marks_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" type="text" name="marks" class="form-control col-sm-8" placeholder="student marks" />

      </div>
    </td>
    <td>


      <input type="hidden" name="student_name" value="something1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="13" />
      <input type="hidden" name="class_id" value="15" />
      <input id="save_btn_<?php echo $value['student_grno'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm save" type="button" value="Save Marks" />


    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```